# where are my return boarding passes

Tags: uk, air-travel, tui

I have checked in online and printed outbound boarding passes but the return boarding passes are not showing up, when can i print them off , Tui flights

Comment: When do you fly back? Check-in and boarding passes are only available a short time before travel.

Comment: You need to check in separately for the return. It opens 14 days ahead so if it is a long vacation it might be too early

Comment: @Anders that sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Willeke: in contrast to most mainline carriers, some budget carriers like TUI or Ryan air open check in 14 days ahead. EZJet is 2 days.

Comment: @Hilmar, when I last used easyJet I could check-in about a month before the flight. But it still a reasonable question to ask.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Depending on where you're going to, COVID regulations might still be in place, or there are some other rules that require the airline to check paperwork at/before boarding. In such situations, the airline might choose not to allow printing of boarding passes at home, even if you're able to "check in", i.e. confirm your data, select a seat and that kind of stuff (happened to me and family members on several occasions).

Answer (score 6):

When is your return flight?

According to [this TUI webpage](https://www.tui.co.uk/flight/faq), you can check in 14 days before your flight:

> WHEN CAN I CHECK IN ONLINE?
>
> If you're flying with TUI, online check-in opens 14 days before your flight takes off. You'll need to check in for your outbound and return flights separately. To see if online check-in is ready for your flights yet, visit our Flight Extras website and enter your booking reference, the surname of the lead passenger and your departure date. You'll then be able to click the Check-in button if it's available.

Comment: Wow, 14 days in advance to check in? American airlines usually give you 24 hours...

Comment: @FreeMan TUI are a charter airline, flying seasonal flights to holiday destinations. That means no business travellers, no (or minor) connections, and very few missed flights, hence no overbooking. At that point, with printed or smartphone passes last minute check ins don't give the company additional information and long check windows are a sales point.

Comment: Thanks, @origimbo, I wasn't aware of that.